# Create a temporary, readonly buffer for test output in Neovim

Tags: neovim, lua, vimscript-lua

I want to create a Neovim plugin that automatically runs a test suite whenever a file is saved. Here's an overview:

1. If I save a Rust file, run `cargo test`
2. If there's not a buffer opened for the test output, automatically create the buffer
3. Mark that buffer as readonly
4. If I save another file, reuse the existing buffer
5. If the buffer is quit (e.g., `:q`), create a new buffer on the next test run

However, I'm currently facing three issues:

1. I cannot detect if when I quit the buffer
2. When the test output is longer than the buffer height, the buffer will not scroll down
3. When I want to quit Neovim, it asks me to save all these temporary buffers (which I don't want to do)

How can I resolve these issues? For reference, here's my code:

```lua
local buffer_number = -1

local function log(_, data)
    if data then
        vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer_number, -1, -1, true, data)
    end
end

local function open_buffer()
    if buffer_number == -1 then
        vim.api.nvim_command('botright vnew')
        buffer_number = vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()
    end
end

local function autotest(pattern, command)
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
        group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("autotest", { clear = true }),
        pattern = pattern,
        callback = function()
            open_buffer()
            vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer_number, 0, -1, true, {})
            vim.fn.jobstart(command, {
                stdout_buffered = true,
                on_stdout = log,
                on_stderr = log,
            })
        end
    })
end

autotest("*.rs", { "cargo", "test" })
```

*P.S. I know there are several existing plugins for testing. I'm creating my own because I want to learn how to write neovim plugins.*

Comment: There’s a help section called… special buffers? Maybe? I think it’s linked to from the `buftype` docs. That might help with the saving problem. For quitting the buffer, you can use an autocommand, but it might be easier to save the buffer and/or window number and see if it exists/is open/etc. You could add `$` as an Ex command after you update the buffer contents (same as `normal! G`). But a simpler method is `terminal` and run a pipeline like `git ls-files | entr -rc cargo test /_`